# map_df -- Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector

Tags: r, purrr

I am an infectious diseases physician and have set myself the challenge of creating a dataframe with the UK cumulative published cases of monkeypox, so I can graph it as a runing tally or a chloropleth map as there is no nice dashboard at present for this.

All the data is published as html webpages rather than as a nice csv so I am trying to scrape it all off the internet using the `rvest` package.

Data is only published intermittently (about twice per week) with the cumulative totals for each of the 4 home nations in UK.

I have managed to get working code to pull data from each of the separate webpages and testing it on the first 2 pages in my `mpx_gov_uk_pages` list works well giving a small example tibble:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rvest)
library(janitor)

# load in overview page url which has links to each date of published cases
mpx_gov_uk_overview_page <- c("https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/monkeypox-outbreak-epidemiological-overview")

# extract urls for each date page
mpx_gov_uk_pages <- mpx_gov_uk_overview_page %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_nodes(".govuk-link") %>%
  html_attr('href') %>% 
  str_subset("\\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-\\d{4}") %>% 
  paste0("https://www.gov.uk", .) %>% 
  as.character()

# make table for home nations for each date
table1 <- mpx_gov_uk_pages[1] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  rename(area = starts_with(c("uk", "devolved")),
         cases = matches(c("total", "confirmed_cases"))) %>%
  separate(cases, c("cases", NA), sep = "\\s\\(") %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(str_extract(mpx_gov_uk_pages[1], "\\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-\\d{4}")),
         cases = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", cases))) %>%
  select(date, area, cases) %>%
  filter(!area %in% c("Total"))

table2 <- mpx_gov_uk_pages[2] %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  rename(area = starts_with(c("uk", "devolved")),
         cases = matches(c("total", "confirmed_cases"))) %>%
  separate(cases, c("cases", NA), sep = "\\s\\(") %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(str_extract(mpx_gov_uk_pages[2], "\\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-\\d{4}")),
         cases = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", cases))) %>%
  select(date, area, cases) %>%
  filter(!area %in% c("Total"))

#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [4].

# Combine tables
bind_rows(table1, table2)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   date       area             cases
#>   <date>     <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1 2022-08-02 England           2638
#> 2 2022-08-02 Northern Ireland    24
#> 3 2022-08-02 Scotland            65
#> 4 2022-08-02 Wales               32
#> 5 2022-07-29 England           2436
#> 6 2022-07-29 Northern Ireland    19
#> 7 2022-07-29 Scotland            61
#> 8 2022-07-29 Wales               30
```

I want to automate this by creating a generic function and passing the list of urls to purrr::map_df as there will be an ever growing number of pages (there's already 13):

```r
pull_first_table <- function(x){
  x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_table() %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    janitor::clean_names() %>% 
    rename(area = starts_with(c("uk", "devolved")),
           cases = matches(c("total", "confirmed_cases"))) %>%
    separate(cases, c("cases", NA), sep = "\\s\\(") %>%
    mutate(date = dmy(str_extract({{x}}, "\\d{1,2}-[a-z]+-\\d{4}")),
           cases = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", cases))) %>%
    select(date, area, cases) %>%
    filter(!area %in% c("Total"))
}

summary_table <- map_df(mpx_gov_uk_pages, ~ pull_first_table)

Error in `dplyr::bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The generic function seems to work ok when I supply it with a single element e.g. `mpx_gov_uk_cases[2]` but I cannot seem to get `map_df` to work properly even though the webscraping is producing tibbles.

All help and pointers greatly welcomed.

Comment: @akrun is spot on about how to do this but I am not sure why would need to pass a list of URLs - wouldn't you download the data each time that the page is updated, so only need to pass one new URL every time the page changes? Also in my experience UK gov data can change format quite often - esp when it is not an official ONS release - so be prepared for this to break often!

Comment: Unfortunately they are posting each update on completly separate urls, rather than updating a single web page; this means you need to scrape each one to get the running totals for each date. I have noticed they changed the tables a lot, hence all the faffing renaming columns. It's been good for practicing and learning how to scrape things off webpages

Comment: My advice would be to use the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) to structure your code. It is easier to have several functions each doing one thing, something like `download_page()`, `scrape_table()`, `clean_names()`, `shape_data()`, `join_tables()`. Then when one thing changes it is easier to fix.

Comment: Thanks. Seems very sensible. I will think about how I can recode it using that principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need the function and not a lambda expression.

```
map_dfr(mpx_gov_uk_pages, pull_first_table)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 52 × 3
   date       area             cases
   <date>     <chr>            <dbl>
 1 2022-08-02 England           2638
 2 2022-08-02 Northern Ireland    24
 3 2022-08-02 Scotland            65
 4 2022-08-02 Wales               32
 5 2022-07-29 England           2436
 6 2022-07-29 Northern Ireland    19
 7 2022-07-29 Scotland            61
 8 2022-07-29 Wales               30
 9 2022-07-26 England           2325
10 2022-07-26 Northern Ireland    18
# … with 42 more rows
```

---

If we use the lambda expression,

```
map_dfr(mpx_gov_uk_pages, ~ pull_first_table(.x))
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I am relatively new to using purrr to automate things, so knew it would be somthing simple